# UWP Command Binding to Button in ItemsControl

Tags: dynamic, data-binding, uwp

In my Xmal I have

```
<Button
   Command = "{Binding FaultClick}"
   />
 </StackPanel>
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FaultButtons}"
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Button command={"Binding FaultCheck"}>
                <Grid>
                   <TextBlock Text={"Binding FaultButtons.Content"}/}
                </Grid>
             </Button>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl,ItemTemplate>
      <ItemsControl>
```

and in my ViewModel I have

```
FaultCheck = new RelayCommand(ClickThisFault,() => true);
```

in the constructor

```
Public RelayCommand FaultCheck
{
   Get;
   Private set;
}
public void ClickThisFault()
{
    some actions
}
```

in the body

What I am trying to achieve is to dynamically build a set of buttons that that the user can click to register faults.

the command binding on the button outside the ItemsControl works fine, I put it there to test the binding.
the itemsource binding on the ItemsControl works as well, my dynamic buttons are created but the Command Binding on the Buttons inside the ItemsControl and the Text Binding on the textBlock dosent work.

Am I missing something with Binding Dynamically created objects ?? or is there a better way to do this??

Comment: I Changed the TextBlock Text Binding to "Binding Content" that fixed that, content comes from the FaultButtons passed to the ItemsControl as an ItemSorce